# How does hWaitForInput work?

Tags: haskell

This bit of code gets characters from `stdin` and converts them to a String. There is a timeout on the input implemented with `hWaitForInput`. I have included the `tryIOError` function to capture `isEOFError`. It times out correctly when the program is run and no input has taken place ie.it is waiting for input. However once a character has been entered it no longer times out. No matter what the input wait time is.

```
-- get string from stdin
getFrmStdIn :: Int -> IO String
getFrmStdIn timeout = do
  inAvail <- tryIOError $ hWaitForInput stdin timeout
  let tOut = either (const False) id inAvail
  if isLeft inAvail
    then return []
  else
    if not tOut
      then die "00 timed out"
    else
      (:) <$> hGetChar stdin <*> getFrmStdIn timeout
```

Answer (score 1):

What OS and GHC version are you using?

AFAIK with the resent `GHC` versions `hWaitForInput` [doesn't work on linux](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/13519) at all when timeout is not 0. On windows the whole IO subsystem is ["a bit lacking"](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/12873#comment:1) too.

Comment: OS  W7 and GHC Ver 8.0.1

Answer (score 1):

> However once a character has been entered it no longer times out. No matter what the input wait time is.

That's how it's supposed to work according to [the docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:hWaitForInput):

> Computation hWaitForInput hdl t waits until input is available on handle hdl. It returns True as soon as input is available on hdl, or False if no input is available within t milliseconds.

Here's a usage example of `hWaitForInput` where it will wait for five seconds and then check if there are characters in `stdin`. If not, it will say "Timeout reached". Otherwise it'll wait for the user to hit enter (`hGetLine` checks for the end of line) and print the user-entered string:

```
main :: IO ()
main =
  hWaitForInput stdin 5000 >>= \inputIsAvailable ->
    if inputIsAvailable
      then hGetLine stdin >>= \input -> putStrLn $ "There is input: " ++ input
      else putStrLn "Timeout reached"
```